# How to set value after add new row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After adding a new row, I need to copy the formulas from the previous cells to the new cells. For example, from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8HAQ.png): the new row is 264, I want through a trigger to paste in cells D264 and I264 the values ​​of the previous cells (so D263 and I263). This must be done every time when a new row is added.

```
function newStajer() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  if(ss.getActiveSheet().getName()==="Экзамены")
  {
    row = ss.getLastRow();
    ss.getRange('1:' + row).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    ss.getRange('D' + row).activate();
    ss.getRange('D' + (row-1)).copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    ss.getRange('I' + row).activate();
    ss.getRange('I' + (row-1)).copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  }
};
```

Comment: Try using a change installable trigger. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help, please show what you tried to make the installable trigger works and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function newStajer() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Экзамены") {
    let row = sh.getLastRow()
    sh.getRange(row - 1, 4).copyTo(sh.getRange(row, 4), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    sh.getRange(row - 1, 9).copyTo(sh.getRange(row, 9), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  }
}
```